# PHP Database - pass as a link or a "reference" to a function?

Tags: php, postgresql

This is not a theoretical or general question about when to use "pass by reference" vs "pass by value". Several questions of that type here, and NONE of them answer my very specific question:

In PHP, when passing a database connection resource ID to a function (just a simple procedural function, not any class or anything complicated) does it matter if I pass by reference or by value?

The connection itself does absolutely nothing. It is never changed. So both reference and value work fine.

My question I suppose is to figure out WHY I would pass it by reference. I have old inherited code, and the comments in the code suggest that passing by reference saves memory and speeds up performance. I wonder if this is true?

Btw I am using Postgresql connections, not MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: This has little (or nothing, really) to do with a database. Consider re-wording more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database connection is a "resource". It is usually just a pointer, so it doesn't matter whether you pass it by value or by reference. Resources behave like objects in this sense.

Passing by reference used to have a significant effect on memory usage in the past. That's why old code contains so many & operators. But this is no longer necessary. PHP 5 uses copy-on-write semantics for variables, so it doesn't cost any more memory to pass things by value in most circumstances. Especially if it's just a pointer like a resource... but this also applies to other types of variables such as string and arrays. (Try passing a 1MB string by value. Memory consumption will NOT go up by 1MB.)

Answer (score 3):

There are no differences in that case because a resource variable is itself a pointer to an external script resources.
Just pass it by value.

You can check how PHP resources are user-friendly if you do `echo $resourceVar;`.
Will print something like: `"Resource id #2"`

Answer (score 2):

For most uses, it doesn't matter at all (usually passing by value), unless you specifically want to change the database connection.

It works similar to objects, in the sense that even when passing an object by value you can still make changes to it because it's a pointer to the actual data.

So to answer the question, there is NO reason for you to pass by reference.